Can I provide the public key to jarsigner on the command line?
I am trying to use jarsigner with a YubiHSM and the SunPKCS11 provider. The code signing cert is 4096-bit. In all other code signing instances, we can provide the matching public key to the signing tool. But, it appears jarsigner requires it to be collocated with the private key on the HSM. I cannot upload the public key to the YubiHSM because I can send a maximum of 2048 bytes in any single request to the device and the cert is too big to fit in that request.
Is there any way to specify the public key to jarsigner without needing to have it collocated in the HSM keystore?

Are you using SunPKCS11, the OS-specific providers/stores (SunMSCAPI, Apple.Keychain), or something else and if so what? The first can't, to my understanding the second should already, and the third depends. If nothing else you can create your own provider similar to SunPKCS11 but change it for offcard certs.

@dave_thompson_085  Yes, I’m using SunPKCS11.
